# How to make Eclipse egit use stored credentials for https repo

Tags: eclipse, egit

Eclipse egit always asks for credentials when contacting bitbucket https repo. How to make it remember them? I already tried the following with no luck:

1. Check 'Store in Secure Store' in Eclipse dialog when entering credentials.
2. git config credential.helper store
3. ~/.netrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating to the newest EGit, version 3.3.2, avaliable from EGit's main update site, see here:

http://eclipse.org/egit/download/

EGit 3.3.1 had [bug 431209](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=431209), which resulted in the credentials not being stored.